# Links em Angular

Tags: angularjs, link

Estou tendo algumas dores de cabeça, pois preciso criar uma função que permita validar quando o link deve redirecionar para o local ou quando não deve por exemplo seu eu estiver carregando uma imagem e ele clicar no link não deve carregar, criei uma função dessas em jquery, mas preciso de uma que seja em angular, podem me ajudar?

segue a função em jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function (event) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        if (alterado === true) {
            //console.log("teste");

            bootbox.confirm('Existem dados não salvos, deseja continuar?', function (resp) {


                if (resp) {
                    location.href = url; // acessa o link indicado na tag a
                } else {
                    event.preventDefault(); // cancela o evento
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: essa variável "alterado" vem de onde?

Comment: de outro controler, apenas uma função que retorna true ou false

Comment: Esse código funciona no jQuery e vc quer converter ele para AngularJS, isso?

Comment: exato, criar uma função que faça a mesma coisa, mas que seja em angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem sua dúvida, mas se quer fazer algo apenas quando a página(rota) estiver completamente carregada você pode utilizar o [$viewContentLoaded](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView).

Exemplo:

**Controller:**

```
  var redirecionar = false;
  $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      redirecionar = true;
      console.log("Rota carregada")
  });

 $scope.acessar = function() {
     if (redirecionar) {
         console.log("Página Carregada! Redirecionando..")
         //implementar redirecionamento
     } else {
         console.log("Pagina não carregada!")
     }
 }
```

**View:**

```
<a href="" ng-click="acessar()">Clique Aqui!</a>
```

Comment: Desculpa Tchies, acho que não me expressei bem, por exemplo: quando eu tem um input text != '' ele não vai permitir redirecionar mas se o input ==== '' ele vai redirecionar, consegue me entender?

Comment: Como assim um input?

Comment: é um exemplo quando eu tiver numa tela com campo input ele vai validar se houve alguma alteração no campo e se tiver alguma alteração no conteúdo do campo ele não vai poder permitir redirecionar, ai vai ter de mandar um $mdDialog questionando se quer prosseguir ou não e que vai perder os dados se prosseguir ai se clicar em sim ele vai permitir redirecionar caso contrário não

Comment: hahah conseguiu entender agora amigo?

Comment: O valor do input será predefinido então?

Comment: vai ser validado dentro de um ng-change por uma variável chamada $scope.foiAlterado = true/false

Comment: Seria mais ou menos isso: http://jsfiddle.net/95wEL/22/

Comment: cara, pelo que eu verifiquei de qualquer forma ele vai redirecionar --- otherwise({redirectTo: 'homepage'}); --- e não dever redirecionar de jeito nenhum nem que seja para a mesma página, entende, tipo ele deve cortar o efeito do href se não tiver false o retorno, consegue entender?

Comment: Cara é por isso que tu deves colocar como quer redirecionar, na pergunta você não especificou pra onde quer redirecionar. Se estiver o otherwisesó vai entrar em vigor caso você chame uma rota inexistente.

Comment: Dentro do if é só fazer a lógica de redirecionamento

Comment: Faça o redirecionamento pelo controller e não pelo href